# Search for matches in a XML file and write all lines contains the match into a new file

Tags: xml, powershell

I need your help.

I've a xml file wich should should be searched for lines containing the chars "thr_".
This lines should be writtten in a new textfile.

I tryed this - it works and printed me the lines containing "thr_" into powershell window:
`gc D:\Test.xml | % { if($_ -match "thr_") {write-host $_}}`

But it wanted to write this down in a new textfile.

The following only creates me (after print the results into powershell window) a blank Outpu file:
`gc D:\Test.xml | % { if($_ -match "thr_") {write-host $_}} >> D:\Out.txt`

Comment: `write-host` only goes to the console. remove it.

Comment: Alternatively, replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output`. There is an `[xml]` type.

Comment: You should be using an XML library to get results.

Comment: You really shouldn't be searching an XML file using tools that are not XML aware. Consider this: what do you want to happen if a chunk of the file has been commented out? Use XPath or XQuery to search XML.

Comment: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or  use `Write-Output $value`). See the linked duplicate for more information.

Comment: thank you all - the answer from lit works as it should :)

for my purposes it's not neccessary to care about xml awareness, because i'm just interested on the values in lines matches my search criteria - not in their correctness.

I just want to read out the values and id tag from these lines into a txt file to import them in a textfield from a word document